# How can I update a nested object in JavaScript and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a data object that I want to update the values inside, but it can be a value inside a nested object. But its exact location is not known.
I put it's parents' names inside each one. A form is created from this object and I need to be able to change the values inside the object by entering the values in the form.

```
obj['key2']['key3']['childern'][key4].value = 'anyting'
```

I don't know how nested this object can be.

**object sample:**

```
obj = {
   "key1":{
      "type":"parent",
      "name":"parent1",
      ...
      "childern":[
         {
            "key2":{
               "type":"any",
               "value":"",
               "parents":[
                  "key1"
               ]
            },
            "key3":{
               "type":"parent",
               "value":"",
               "parents":[
                  "key1"
               ],
               "childern":[
                  {
                     "key4":{
                        "type":"any",
                        "value":"",
                        "parents":[
                           "key1",
                           "key3"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know how nested it will be, how will you know which value you want to update? Also this seems to be invalid JSON since it uses `=` instead of `:` to assign values in many places, but not all.

Comment: @FiniteLooper    I have a function to print parent and child that creates only one form in a loop. Thus, when the form is created, I have the parent's name and the child's details.

Comment: To clarify his question. I understand it to mean he wants to pass a subset of this big object to some form, that when submitted, edits that subset as part of the larger object. @RaanaTashakori Life will be a lot easier for you if you use Immer for this https://immerjs.github.io/immer/

Comment: Can you give some sample output from this function?

Comment: @RaanaTashakori When the form is created you also then have a reference to the object. You don't need to edit that subobject by going like `obj['key2']['key3']['childern'][key4]`. Because when you instantiate the form, you already have the nested object at hand. Mutating it, will also mutate it in the parent structure. Because objects are copy by reference in JS.

Comment: `Object.keys` to iterate over your object and then do that recursively.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the name of the last key you can try flattening your structure, which will work because of how javascript handles passing objects by reference

```
function flattenRecursive(obj){

  let children = {}
  const objKeys = Object.keys(obj)
  objKeys.forEach(objKey => {
    if(obj[objKey].children){
      obj[objKey].children.forEach(child => {
        children = {...children, ...flattenRecursive(child)}
      })
    }
  })
  return {...obj, ...children}
}
```

then you can simply do

```
const newObj = flattenRecursive(obj)
newObj['key4'].value = 'anything'
```

now the value of

```
obj['key2']['key3']['childern'][key4].value
```

should also be 'anything'

Comment: I just tested this and it worked for me